# NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `use_transactional_fixtures with cucumber selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I have got the error when i have written

```
RSpec.configure do |c| 
    c.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    c.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `use_transactional_fixtures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write this code in rspec.rb file

Answer (score 3):

You may not have installed the

```
gem 'rspec-rails'
```

or maybe you didn't require it on your specs as

```
require 'rspec/rails'
```

**use_transaction_fixtures** is part of the *rspec-rails gem* here:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb#L31

Hope this helps you

Regards

ED